# JAVA:How can I update my arraylist value (using singleton), asigning another value, it keeps erroring out

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to do a ATM system for a school project.
I am not sure how to update an ArrayList value using singleton, please help!!!

I am trying to do something like `Balance=Balance-withdrawAmount`, but it keeps erroring out.

```
    public class Users {

        private static Users instance = null;
        public static List<String> cta = null;                                            
        public List<List<String>> accounts = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        private Users() {
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("259853430", "0191", "active","admin","Phil","Anselmo","500000","Citi"));
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("100393938", "0330", "blocked","regular","Trent","Reznor","100000","Citi"));
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("205000800", "0180", "active","regular","Troy","Smith","2006620","Scotiabank"));
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("109000600", "0370", "active","regular","James","Hetfield","5049973","Citi"));
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("202000500", "0350", "active","regular","Tom","Araya","2240070","JPMorgan"));
            accounts.add(Arrays.asList("110000200", "1270", "active","regular","Dave","Mustain","3000300","Citi"));
        }

        public static Users getObject() {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = new Users();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }  

    ////////////////////// in a different class


    public class UsuarioNormalMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent MenuNormal) {
            Users run = Users.getObject();
    [ ... ]

                    if(ok_cancel == -1) {

                        if(Double.parseDouble(withdrawAmount) > Double.parseDouble(Users.cta.get(6))) { 
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"<html><font size = 3.5><font color = black>"
                                                        + "Inssuficient Funds. " ,"Withdraw",
                                                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        else if(Double.parseDouble( withdrawAmount)==Double.parseDouble(Users.cta.get(6))) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"<html><font size = 3.5><font color = black>"
                                                            + "Zero Balance!", 
                                                            null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
                        }
                        else if(Mod==0) {

                        // THIS IS WHERE IT IS ERRORING OUT, I WANT TO DO SOMETHING LIKE
                        //Balance=Balance-withdrawAmount; BUT IT DOESNT

                           double newBalance =  Double.parseDouble(Users.cta.get(6)) - (Double.parseDouble(withdrawAmount));
                            Double.parseDouble(Users.cta.set(6)) = newBalance;


                                //The error message i get is:
                        // required: int,String
                        //found: int
                        //reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
                        //where E is a type-variable:
                        //E extends Object declared in interface List
```

Comment: focus on `Users.cta.set(6)`

Comment: I added the error message at the end of the code as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign the result of a primitive method to a value (`Double.parseDouble()` returns a primitive `double`)

```
Double.parseDouble(Users.cta.set(6)) = newBalance;
```

Should be something like

```
Users.cta.set(6, Double.toString(newBalance));
```